# Prove ${k \choose k} + {k + 1 \choose k} + {k + 2 \choose k} + ... + {n \choose k} = {n + 1 \choose k+1}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, summation, binomial-coefficients

I have the following problem at discrete maths subject on college.
Let's say that $k, n ∈ {0, 1, 2, 3, ...}$ and $k <= n$.
Prove the following:
${k \choose k} + {k + 1 \choose k} + {k + 2 \choose k} + ... + {n \choose k} = {n + 1 \choose k+1}$

Comment: What ideas do you have?

Comment: Try looking at the hockey-stick identity: http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Wiki/index.php/Combinatorial_identity

Comment: This is trivial to prove by Pascal's identity.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We have $n+1$ people lined up om a row, and want to choose $k+1$ of them to get a prize. This can be done in $\binom{n+1}{k+1}$ ways. We do the counting another way.

We can choose the first person,  and $k$ from the last $n$. There are $\binom{n}{k}$ ways to do this.

We can skip the first person, choose the second, and pick $k$ from the last $n-1$.
There are $\binom{n-1}{k}$ ways to do this.

We can skip the first two, choose the third, and $k$ more.

And so on.

Finally, we skip the first $(n+1)-(k+1)$, choose the next, and $k$ from the last $k$. There are $\binom{k}{k}$ ways to do this.

We get the desired sum, backwards.

Answer (score 3):

The relation in Pascal's Triangle says
$$
\binom{j}{k}=\binom{j+1}{k+1}-\binom{j}{k+1}
$$
Sum in $j$ from $k$ to $n$:
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{j=k}^n\binom{j}{k}
&=\sum_{j=k}^n\left[\binom{j+1}{k+1}-\binom{j}{k+1}\right]\\
&=\sum_{j=k+1}^{n+1}\binom{j}{k+1}-\sum_{j=k}^n\binom{j}{k+1}\\
&=\binom{n+1}{k+1}-\binom{k}{k+1}\\
&=\binom{n+1}{k+1}
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 3):

Let $k \in \mathbb{N}$.

**Base:** $n=k$: $\binom{n}{k}=\binom{n}{n}=1=\binom{n+1}{n+1}=\binom{n+1}{k+1}$.

**Hypothesis:** $\exists (n-1) \in \mathbb{N}: (n-1) \geq k \land \sum_{i=k}^{n-1} \binom{i}{k} = \binom{n}{k+1} =  \binom{(n-1)+1}{k+1}$

**Step:** $$\sum_{i=k}^{n} \binom{i}{k} = \binom{n}{k+1} + \binom{n}{k}  = \frac{n!}{(k+1)(n-k-1)!k!} + \frac{n!}{(n-k)(n-k-1)!k!} = \frac{(n-k+k+1)n!}{(n-k)!(k+1)!}  = \frac{(n+1)!}{(n-k)!(k+1)!} = \binom{n+1}{k+1}$$
And the proposition is proved using induction.

**Notice** that the **Step** is actually proof of Pascal's rule.

Answer (score 2):

Lemma: ${n+1\choose k+1}={n\choose k+1}+{n\choose k} $

Proof: Fix an element in $n+1$ elements.

If you will not choose it you have ${n\choose k+1}$ choices.

If you will choose it you have ${n\choose k} $ choices.Thus ,we are done.

If you apply this lemma untill you reach $k+1$,you will get;

$${k+1\choose k+1}+{k+1\choose k}+{k+2\choose k}+...{n\choose k}={n+1\choose k+1}$$

Since,${k+1\choose k+1}={k\choose k}$ we are done.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this question using the basic binomial theorem of Grade 11 Mathematics (The grade I am in right now...) Hope you understand it.

We are trying to find the coefficient of $x^k$ in the expansion of

$$f(x)=(1+x)^k+(1+x)^{k+1}+\cdots+(1+x)^n$$

This will give us

$${k\choose k}+{k+1\choose k}+\cdots +{n\choose k}$$

So let's find $f(x)$. This is a GP, so

$$
\begin{split}
f(x)&=\frac{(1+x)^k[(1+x)^{n-k+1}-1]}{(1+x)-1}\\
&=\frac{(1+x)^{n+1}-(1+x)^k}{x}\\
\end{split}
$$

Now we need to find the coefficient of $x^k$ in the above expansion of $f(x)$. Equivalently, this is the coefficient of $x^{k+1}$ in

$$(1+x)^{n+1}-(1+x)^k$$

which is clearly equal to ${n+1\choose k+1}$ by the binomial theorem. Therefore

$${k\choose k}+{k+1\choose k}+\cdots +{n\choose k}={n+1\choose k+1}$$

Note: Original Answer at https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cd9Ir.jpg

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers. Alternatively, you should format your math with MathJax. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Sure Sir... I had attempted this question on a piece of paper and I have attached the same. I will make sure to type out next time

Comment: Though I would normally advise against answering old posts with lots of answers, it seems your solution is genuinely different from the other answers, and is in my opinion, a good contribution to the site. It would be a shame if it was downvoted or removed because of the lack of formatting. Therefore, I have made an edit to your answer to transcribe your solution into text, and make some minor modifications so your solution is more understandable. Feel free to accept or reject the edit.$\tag*{}$Welcome to MSE, and keep up the good work. : )

Comment: Thank You so much for taking the effort to transcribe my answer.